# Failing to update a table

Tags: delphi

I have a boolean field in cxGrid (represented as a checkbox inside the grid).
I am trying to do an update of the very same record when user sets the checkbox as checked.

I tried this:

```
procedure TDataModule3.ABSTable2BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
if DataModule3.ABSTable2.FieldByName('DONE').AsBoolean = True then
with Datamodule3.ABSQuery4 do begin
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.Close;
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.SQL.Text :='UPDATE MYTABLE SET USER=:a1 where TW_ID =:a2';
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsString := MainForm.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text ;
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a2').AsInteger := Datamodule3.ABSTable2.FieldByName('TW_ID').AsInteger;
Datamodule3.ABSQuery4.ExecSQL;
end;
end;
```

I get :
First chance exception at $00B6E33F. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00b6e33f: read of address 0x000003a0'. Process Project1.exe (4916)

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: I tried the suggestion.

/

```
if ABSTable2.FieldByName('Done').AsBoolean = True then
  begin
  ABSQuery4.Close;
  ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
  ABSQuery4.SQL.Text :='UPDATE mytable SET user=:a1 where  TW_ID=:a2 ';
  ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsString := ABSQuery1.FieldByName('USER').asString ;
  ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a2').AsInteger := ABSTable2.FieldByName('TW_ID').AsInteger;
   ABSQuery4.ExecSQL;
  end;
```

I have removed the reference to the main form and added the query  syntax as the AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text gets its data from it.
Now I get: Absolute Engine error : The table is locked.

Comment: Try and remove the `Datamodule3.` from all of the lines. Your with statement is also completely unnecessary. There is a chance that MainForm is the one giving an access violation but there is no way for us to tell because you didn't tell us what line of code the error occurred on.

Comment: Your new error related to ABS ("the table is locked") is a totally separate issue, and therefore a totally separate question. The question here was about the access violation, which has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `DataModule3` from the beginning of all of the lines of code.

You're using an instance variable inside the methods of a class. If the instance is named anything other than `DataModule3` or `DataModule3` hasn't been created, your code will fail.

The proper way to write the code would be (see the **NOTE** below):

```
procedure TDataModule3.ABSTable2BeforePost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if Self.ABSTable2.FieldByName('DONE').AsBoolean = True then
  begin
    Self.ABSQuery4.Close;
    Self.ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
    Self.ABSQuery4.SQL.Text :='UPDATE MYTABLE SET USER=:a1 where TW_ID =:a2';

    // See NOTE below
    Self.ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a1').AsString := MainForm.AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[3].Text ;
    Self.ABSQuery4.Params.ParamByName('a2').AsInteger :=    Self.ABSTable2.FieldByName('TW_ID').AsInteger;
    ABSQuery4.ExecSQL;
  end;
end;
```

**NOTES**

1. The `Self` is optional. You could write each without the `Self.` and it would work equally as well in this case. `Self` refers to the current instance of the object, rather than a specific named instance like `DataModule3` does.
2. You should find a way to remove the reference to `MainForm` and a visual component by adding an instance variable or property to the datamodule class instead that you can refer to in your code. Hard-coding in the `MainForm` can cause the same kind of problems that hard-coding in `DataModule3` - it's a specific instance name rather than just being the current instance of something. If you rename your `MainForm` to something else, your code won't compile. If you replace `MainForm` with a different form, but there's another `MainForm` in scope that hasn't been created yet, your code will also crash.

Comment: I did it another way :if ABSTable2.FieldByName('done').AsBoolean = True then
DataSet['user'] := absquery1.FieldByName('user').AsString
else  DataSet['user'] :='';